# MATLAB Multiple Maximum Values

Tags: matlab, max

I am having problem with MATLAB's maximum function. What I am supposed to do is to replace the maximum value of an array with a number. However, when there are more than one maximal value, the program updates all of them simultaneously. Is there a way to make it do it one by one? The order of replacement is not important; it can be done arbitrarily. The only important thing is to have MATLAB doing it one by one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean "one by one"? Please provide example data and the code you have.

Comment: a=[5 5];
b=max(a);
c=b-2;
a=changem(a,c,b);
disp(a)

When this code is run, the program updates both the first and the second rows of the vector a. So, it prints [3 3]. What I want it to print is either [5,3] or [3,5]. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Please don't provide details as comments, instead edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second output of `max` returns one index:

```
a=[5,5];
[b,idx]=max(a)
c=b-2;
a(idx)=c
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to solve my problem. However, I have one quick question. Could you please explain what (idx) stands for and what it does?

Comment: It returns the index of one maximum. Try a larger example where the first isn't the maximum to understand.

Answer (score 0):

When you say more than 1 maximum value, I assume you are talking about a matrix where `max` function operates on every column?

You can do the following:

```
a = [1 1 2;5 5 7; 3 2 9]
```

Obviously, the maximum value is going to be 9, but if you do the following:

```
max(a)
```

The result will be:

```
5 5 9
```

Based on each column.

The following may work for you?

```
max(a(:)) % Maximum value from a matrix (rerranged into 1 column)
```

you can do the same for the `min` function.